# Andengine ParticleSystem as Livewallpaper problems

Tags: andengine, live-wallpaper, particles

First, I'll post link here where all is described by another person already
http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/particle-system-in-live-wallpaper-t8035.html

Well, the thing is, I set the ParticleSystem as a livewallpaper, and after the phone goes to sleep and I wake him up all particles are spawned at once. MaxRate and MinRate are ignored, max particles set in code is taken and the maxparticles possible are spawned.

But doesn't happens always, only sometimes. in 2 days it made this 3 times.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Question for ppl that know and engine.

Ty